# Unable to start mediarecorder for front camera, it throws illegalStateException start failed: -38

Tags: android, video, camera

What is the meaning of start failed: -38?

I created two `CameraView`(Preview) Objects and one Camera Object.

Using Handlers I am able to switch the camera for some times, say, 10 secs open back camera and 10 secs open front camera.

Now I am facing some issue in recording front camera.

When I click the record button, first it will record back camera for 10 secs, and save it into sd card. and after 10 secs automatically it switches to front camera to record.

Back camera recording is working fine. But front camera preview is showing correctly, but it is not recording video, it says `IllegalStateException start failed: -38` when I call `mediarecorder.start();`

here is the code

**Prepare Media**

```
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    mCamera.unlock(); // lock camera for later use


    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera); // lock camera for later use

    //mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera); // lock camera for later use
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    //mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P));
    //mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));
    //mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(320, 240);
    //mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(15);

    //mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    //mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264);
    long l = System.currentTimeMillis();
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile("/sdcard/" + l + ".mp4");
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(600000); // Set max duration 60 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
        Log.e(TAG, "prepareMediaRecorder: ");
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    Log.e(TAG, "prepareMediaRecorder: RETURN TRUE");
```

**Start Record**

```
if (!prepareMediaRecorder()) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Fail in prepareMediaRecorder()!\n - Ended -", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        //finish();
        return;
    }

    try {
        Log.e(TAG, "recordBackCameraVideo: START START ");
        mediaRecorder.start();
        Log.e(TAG, "recordBackCameraVideo: START END ");
    } catch (final Exception ex) {
        Log.i("---", "Exception in thread");
    }

    recording = true;
```

**Stop Recording**

```
try {
        Log.e(TAG, "stopRecording: STOP START");
        mediaRecorder.stop(); // stop the recording
        Log.e(TAG, "stopRecording: STOP END");
    } catch (RuntimeException stopException) {
        Log.e(TAG, "stopRecording: " + stopException.getMessage());
    }
    releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Video captured!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    recording = false;
```

Comment: Because your front camera does not support CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_720P this quality try to decrease the quality and then try It will work sir.

Comment: see my answer sir.

Comment: the same profile settings works for demo, where there is a button to switch camera, and that demo is working fine for front and back camera

Comment: and i am using the same device for demo as well as my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one. First you need to check CamcorderProfile.hasProfile("CameraID", "Pass your desired quality") If it is true then you can use that quality for video recording otherwise you need to use some other CamcorderProfile quality.

Below code is just for the reference which I used in my project you can change the code according to your need.

```
private boolean prepareMediaRecorder() {
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();

    CamcorderProfile profile = null;
    if (!cameraFront) {
        profile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
    } else {
        if (CamcorderProfile.hasProfile(0, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH)) {
            profile = CamcorderProfile.get(0, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH);
        } else {
            profile = CamcorderProfile.get(0, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
        }
    }

    mCamera.unlock();
    if (!cameraFront) {
        // Back
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(90);
    } else {
        // Front
        mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
    }
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(mCamera);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(profile.fileFormat);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(Utils.getOriginalFileName());
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(50000); // Set max duration 5 sec.
    mediaRecorder.setMaxFileSize(50000000); // Set max file size 50M

    try {
        mediaRecorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        releaseMediaRecorder();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: the same profile settings works for demo, where there is a button to switch camera, and that demo is working fine for front and back camera

Comment: Which video size you are using for recording the video?

Comment: i didn't specified any video size

Comment: i used this also mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);, then also the same problem

Comment: can you tell me what is the meaning of -38

Comment: Make sure you do not forget this uses-permission and uses-features in manifest file.
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.camera.front"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

Comment: yeah, i used all of these permissions

Comment: Okey and which profile ( mediaRecorder.setProfile() ) you are using for it. the same 720p quality?

Comment: That is the problem I already mentioned on my first comment that your front camera does not support that quality 720P. try this quality mediaRecorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW));

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154504/discussion-between-andy-developer-and-demo-mail).